# TCL: file normalize gives unexpected output

Tags: tcl

I have the following line of code:

```
file normalize [string map {\\ /} $file]
```

The string map operation is to make the line work for paths containing backslashes instead of forward (as is the case in Windows)

For some values of $file (let's say it's "/path/to/my/file") I get output similar to:

```
/path/to/"/path/to/my/file/"
```

This doesn't happen for all paths but I'm unable to figure out what causes it. There are no symbolic links in the path.
Is there something I'm doing wrong, or is there an alternative to file normalize that I could try?

my tcl version is 8.5

UPDATE:
On further investigation I see that the `string map` is not making any difference. The output of `file normalize` itself is coming with that extra text before the desired text. Also, the extra text seems to be from a previous run of the code.

UPDATE 2: It was because of the quotation marks in the input to `file normalize`

Comment: You don't need to translate slash->backslash to use a path string in Windows. Tcl handles delimiter differences automatically.

Comment: I see, that's good to know. The problem however is with the return string of the file normalize operation and it happens on linux (where the string map doesn't do anything)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the path has backslashes where it shouldn't have them.

```
% file normalize {"/path/to/some/file"}
/path/to/"/path/to/some/file"
% file normalize \"/path/to/some/file\"
/path/to/"/path/to/some/file"
```

Perhaps some pathname handling code escaped special characters for some reason and left the path in a mangled state.

I would try to keep the pathname pristine and when it needs to be changed for display or other processing, make a copy of it first.

Comment: I found that the problem isn't with the string map (updated the question). Do you know any way to fix the stale prefix coming in the file normalize output?

Comment: The prefix is not stale, the input to `file normalize` is not a valid path.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand. I've verified that the path exists on disk, also the prefix that is getting printed is from a previous run of the code which has nothing to do with the current $file variable. Does that change your answer?

Comment: No, that does not change my answer.   You need solve the underlying problem, which is "Why does the path have quote marks attached to it?  Did they get escaped?", not try to work around the bad data afterwards.

Comment: Thanks Brad! It was the quotation marks. Couldn't catch that from your earlier comments.